# SQLAlchemy: Map a column value before storage

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Perhaps I am approaching this wrongly.

Say I have an enum like so:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
  type0 = 'type0'
  type1 = 'type1'
```

And a SQLAlchemy ORM Schema like so:

```
class MyEntity(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'my_entity'
  id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

I don't want to store `MyEnum` in the database as an entity type. I just want it to be as a string, with no validation. However, whenever I access `MyEntity.name`, I want it to have been cast to an enum.

Is there any way to do a simple mapping so that, from the outside, it looks as though `MyEntity.name` is of type `MyEnum`, but is persisted as a raw string?

The closest thing I have found was to use a [hybrid_property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_attributes.html#using-descriptors-and-hybrids), but this doesn't seem to be applied for my exact use-case.

Any ideas?